# Transitive groups that are not primitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to seek some examples of transitive groups that are not primitive. I found out this article [Generating Symmetric Groups](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974644?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) where is shown as example the group $G \subset S_6$ induced by rotations of the cube.

Following the line of the above example I thought also the group induced by rotations of the square does our business, and thus the whole $D_4$ (rotations and reflections of the square) group is a good example.

Can anybody know other toy-examples?

Comment: By definition, subgroup of $S_4$ that preserves $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$ seems to be the minimal example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any subgroup of $Sym(n)$ of the form $Sym(k)\wr Sym(l)$ where $n=kl$ fits the criteria (this comes from the [O'Nan-Scott Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Nan%E2%80%93Scott_theorem)).  This construction is known as the [wreath product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product).  Concretely this is the stabilizer of a partition into $k$ parts of size $l$.

Here is a fully worked example in $Sym(6)$:

Consider two blocks of size $3$: $\{1,2,3\}, \{4,5,6\}$, take all permutations that preserve these subsets in $Sym(6)$, i.e $H=Sym(\{1,2,3\})$ and $K=Sym(\{4,5,6\})$.  Now find a $g\in Sym(6)$ which switches the two blocks, for example $g=(14)(25)(36)$.  Now let $G=\langle H,K,g\rangle$.  Then $G$ acts transitively and imprimitively on 6 points.  Note that $G\cong Sym(2)\wr Sym(3)$.

The minimal example alluded to in the comments has generating set $\langle(12),(34),(13)(24)\rangle$.  That is, it is exactly the set of permutations that preserve 2 sets of 2.  A non trivial block structure is then given almost by definition: $1\sim2$ and $3\sim4$.